# Add ng-click to highcharts-ng column chart xAxis labels

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts-ng

I am using highcharts-ng within an angular app, I need to run a function when the xAxis labels are clicked see below the categories and labels I am adding to the chart.

Currently I can add an onclick to the label and alert but am not able to get this to work with angular.

```
return "<a onclick='alert(1)'>" + this.value + "</a>";
```

http://pablojim.github.io/highcharts-ng/

Working example of current code here.
http://jsfiddle.net/3gLr4vcu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular directives are not processed until $compile is called, which is usually done when Angular inserts templates, for directives and ng-include for instance. If you modify the DOM yourself, Angular doesn't know quite what do with the HTML unless you call $compile yourself. After the DOM is modified by highcharts-ng, you will need to call $compile like this:

```
$compile(element)(scope)
```

Ideally you want **element** to be an element that hasn't been $compiled already (I am unsure what happens if that is not the case) and **scope** to be first scope encountered in an upwards traversal of the DOM tree. If the scope hierarchy is not needed, then you can just attach the element to the $rootScope.

You will need to inject $compile (as well as $rootScope if you use it as described). For more information, see the [$compile documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile), which also explains the odd syntax off the $compile expression. If you post your full code, I can tell you where to put the $compile statement and how to find the appropriate scope to use.

EDIT: Here is a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tsclaus/bpg4556c/